# expect_equal fails due to different keys in data.table

Tags: r, unit-testing, mockery, testthat

I have written a very simple unit test, but it keeps failing due to a different key in data.table:

`out` is the actual outcome of my function and `expectedOut` is something that I have defined:

```
  extectedOut <- data.table(
    ID = c("ID-1", "ID-2"), 
    Name = c("product-1", "product-2"), 
    type = c("N-1", "N-2")
  )
```

I have run the unit test using `test_that` and it fails with the error message:

> Datasets has different keys. 'target': ID. 'current' has no key.

they look the same, but looking at the structure one indeed has a key.

```
> str(out)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID: chr  "ID-1" "ID-2"
 $ Name: chr  "name-1" "name-2"
 $ type    : chr  "N-1" "N-2"
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "ID"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> str(extectedOut)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID: chr  "ID-1" "ID-2"
 $ Name: chr  "product-1" "product-2"
 $ type    : chr  "N-1" "N-2"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

How can I avoid this error from happening?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to set the keys of the dataset to NULL before applying the `expect_equal`

```
library(data.table)
setkey(out, NULL)
```

---

`expect_equal` is based on `all.equal`, so we may also use `check.attributes` as `FALSE`

```
> out <- copy(extectedOut)
>setkey(out, "ID")

> expect_equal(extectedOut, out)
Error: `extectedOut` not equal to `out`.
Datasets have different keys. 'target': has no key. 'current': [ID].
> expect_equal(extectedOut, out, check.attributes = FALSE)
```

Comment: Surely it's better to amend the expected output to match the actual - correct - output than vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expect_equivalent`:

```r
library(data.table)
Out <- data.table(
  ID = c("ID-1", "ID-2"), 
  Name = c("product-1", "product-2"), 
  type = c("N-1", "N-2")
)
expectedOut <- data.table(
  ID = c("ID-1", "ID-2"), 
  Name = c("product-1", "product-2"), 
  type = c("N-1", "N-2")
)

setkey(Out,ID)

testthat::expect_equivalent(Out,expectedOut)

testthat::expect_equal(Out,expectedOut)
#> Error: `expectedOut` not equal to `Out`.
#> Datasets has different keys. 'target': ID. 'current' has no key.
```